# Codeigniter Sybase Database Configuration

Tags: codeigniter, sybase

If I connect to Sybase using ODBC, what setting should I use in the database.php file?

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "";
```

I know for mysql hostname is localhost and dbdriver is mysql. What about Sybase? What should be place in hostname? And the dbdriver? Is it ODBC?

Thanks.

Comment: What Sybase product are you trying to connect to?  ASE, SQLAnywhere?  Have you downloaded the Sybase ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $db['default']['hostname'] = "Driver=Adaptive Server Anywhere 7.0;ENG=your_server_sybase  ;UID=youruser;PWD=yourpswrd;DBN='';LINKS=TCPIP(HOST=127.0.0.1:9000) "
```

---

HOST=127.0.0.1:9000
 port 9000

or 
 HOST=127.0.0.1

---

```
 $db['default']['username'] = "";
 $db['default']['password'] = "";
 $db['default']['database'] = "";
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "odbc";
```